# Unknown PUSH_ACTION for ETPushService: com.geico.mobile.MESSAGE_OPENED

Tags: error-messages, mobilepush-android

I am getting following error when I press on custom action button for a Rich notification ...

> Unknown PUSH_ACTION for ETPushService: (applicatinId).MESSAGE_OPENED
>                                                                    ~!ETPush_ERROR:  ET PUSH SDK VERSION: 4.2.0 build 160100043
>                                                                    ~!ETPush_ERROR:  APP VERSION: 4.6.0 LOCAL : 83
>                                                                    ~!ETPush_ERROR:  Debug version: true
>                                                                    ~!ETPush_ERROR:  readyAimFire() Initialized with: 
>                                                                    ~!ETPush_ERROR:  ET App Id: {et_app_id}
>                                                                    ~!ETPush_ERROR:  Access Token: {access_token}
>                                                                    ~!ETPush_ERROR:  GCM Sender ID: {gcm_sender_id}
>                                                                    ~!ETPush_ERROR:  Analytics: false
>                                                                    ~!ETPush_ERROR:  WAMA: false
>                                                                    ~!ETPush_ERROR:  Location: false
>                                                                    ~!ETPush_ERROR:  Proximity: false
>                                                                    ~!ETPush_ERROR:  CloudPages: false
>                                                                    ~!ETPush_ERROR:  GOOGLE PLAY SERVICES REQUIRED VERSION AVAILABLE: true
>                                                                    ~!ETPush_ERROR:  GOOGLE PLAY SERVICES REQUIRED VERSION: 8487000

I am using following code to build Rich notification with a custom action

```
ETNotifications.setNotificationBuilder(new ETNotificationBuilder() {
            @Override
            public Builder setupNotificationBuilder(Context context, Bundle payload) {
                NotificationCompat.Builder builder = ETNotifications.setupNotificationBuilder(context, payload);

                String category = payload.getString("category");
                            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(category )) {
                    if ("Testing".equalsIgnoreCase(messageCode)) {
                        //we need to add the 3 item_spotlight buttons to the notification. Android allows
                        //a max of 3 action buttons on the BigStyle notifications.
                        Intent similarIntent = new Intent(context, AceRichNotificationMakePaymentActivity.class);
                        similarIntent.putExtras(payload);
                        PendingIntent similarPendingIntent = ETNotifications.createPendingIntentWithOpenAnalytics(context, similarIntent, true);
                        builder.addAction(R.drawable.ic_action_remove, "Pay Now", similarPendingIntent);

                    } else if (ONE_DAY_SALE.equalsIgnoreCase(category)) {
                        //get custom key for the sale date.
                        String saleDateString = payload.getString("sale_date");
                        if (saleDateString != null && !saleDateString.isEmpty()) {
                            try {
                                SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.getDefault());
                                df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
                                Date saleDate = df.parse(saleDateString);

                                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT)
                                        .setData(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI)
                                        .putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, saleDate.getTime())
                                        .putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME, saleDate.getTime())
                                        .putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, payload.getString("event_title"))
                                        .putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, payload.getString("alert"))
                                        .putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.HAS_ALARM, 1)
                                        .putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_ALL_DAY, true);

                                PendingIntent reminderPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 38456, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
                                builder.addAction(R.drawable.ic_audio, "Add Reminder", reminderPendingIntent);
                            } catch (ParseException e) {
                                Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                return builder;
            }
        });
```

Comment: do you have more than 1 push provider in your application?

Comment: nope. we use only ExactTarget or ET..

Comment: I will implement this in the Android Learning App and get back with you.  I see that you're using v4.2.  Any chance you'd consider upgrading to v4.5?  :)  Note, none of this code has changed in a very long time so I do not propose that it will fix the issue you've described above.  You can see the full release notes http://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/JB4A-SDK-Android/

Comment: Well, apparently this is a thing.  I'm opening an internal ticket for prioritization by Product.  Creating a formal escalation through your account manager will help expedite the remediation ;)

Comment: If you have not reached out to your account manager yet, please do so.  It will raise visibility and get your issue prioritized appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been validated.  An internal ticket has been created and this item is actively being worked for a future release of the SDK.  As of right now it is expected to be released with the version corresponding to the 2016-06 SFMC release.

Please watch http://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/JB4A-SDK-Android/ for details and ask that your account manager notify you when 2016-06 is released.

This item is resolved with version 4.7.3 of the SDK.